# Deleted Local Repositories Constantly Showing up in Trash

Tags: github

Having an issue that is driving me nuts. I deleted a few local repositories ever since they have been showing up in my trash constantly, typically upon opening from a lock screen or a restart. These repositories were originally saved in my icloud folder, not sure if that could be the issue here. They have never shown back up in the original folder and it wont even allow me to restore them when they are in the trash

its also has multiple folders in the trash with the same name. Wondering if anyones ever encountered this before

Screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6L6z.jpg